# Correct the phrase 'u need a girl whose looks doesn't matter to her'

Tags: word-usage, phrase-usage, phrasing

Link to video: https://vt.tiktok.com/ZSNsL7FqE/

[image: Screenshot of the comment in question]

The context of the video is that this guy has some demanding expectations for a girl.

The following comment was made:

> u need a girl whose looks doesn't matter to her

My interpretation is that the **intended** meaning of the comment is that this guy needs a girl that does not care about looks (because he's not good looking).

However, `whose` is possessive so the literal meaning is that he needs a girlfriend that doesn't care about *her own looks*.

The replies and number of likes on the comment leads be to believe that many people have no issues with reading and understanding it, which makes me question my own understanding and usage of 'whose'.

What's the right way to phrase it to keep the intended meaning without changing the structure of the sentence? Note that the second comment ('you need a girl who can accept your looks tbh') is example of what I believe is has the same intended meaning as the first comment but with a less confusing structure.

The best I can come up with is:

> u need a girl who looks doesn't matter to her

But it still doesn't feel quite right to me...

Comment: Spoken language that is colloquial can be considered full of mistakes from a standard point of view. So, what are you asking?? The phrase in your title is non standard but that is due to the verb.

Comment: The first comment is so close to illiterate that no-one would be expected to read its intended meaning without context. We don't have enough context here. Does it echo the sentiment of the second comment or is it meant to oppose it? I can't decide from the first comment alone whether the subject is the guy in the photo or a girl he would like to attract. *The really scary thing is that 9,000 people think they can decipher it.*

Comment: In standard English: 'You need a girl whose looks don't matter to her'. 'whose' is standard (in making a realtive clause the sentence that is relativized is 'Her looks don't matter' and 'whose' replaces 'her'. 'doesn't' is not standard ('looks' acts like a singular). This question is not really a good fit for ELU - we don't really 'correct' grammar. Maybe [ELL.SE] would be better?

Comment: The editor has provided the answer!

Comment: When a suggested edit adds 《*I want to form a sentence which refers to a girl* **for whom a person's looks don't matter**.》 And the OP later says the best sentence they came up with is《 *u need* **a girl who looks doesn't matter to her**》this makes the question look very paradoxical.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the best expression of what you think the intended phase would be, "You need a girl to whom/for whom looks don't matter."